# A table row was 4 columns wide and exceeded the column count established using column markup, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, validation

How do I go about fixing this error? It gives me this error five times when I am validating my code. Thank you for the help. A table row was 4 columns wide and exceeded the column count established using column markup (1).

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: @ZaheerUlHassan not all the questions need to have code, visit How to Ask too

Comment: @almartinez read the question carefully. we are not mind readers here. :/

Comment: @ZaheerUlHassan yes already read it, I don't know how to answer then i just leave it be, he's new, trying to help him from "send me the code" guys

Comment: We are also here to help these guys but how can we help without getting there actual problem. we also tell them how to ask? it will improve there questioning level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the number of columns as specified with `col` elements the same as the number of columns as specified by table cell markup (`th` and `td` elements, with due attention to `colspan` attributes). It is possible that the simplest solution is to add `col` elements for the extra columns, but it is also possible that there is some mistake in table cell markup, causing some row to occupy more columns than intended.